# I think I need an linked list structure with keys. Any suggestions?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I want to store data in a `map` structure because I need to access elements using a key. I will also be iterating over consecutive elements, so a `list` structure would be my best choice here. I think I need a hybrid data structure that offers the best of both worlds.

So basically I want random access with *O(log(n))* complexity and iteration with *O(c)* complexity. Are there any built-in structures from `cstdlib` or Qt that might be worth considering? Are there alternative approaches that might be more appropriate in this case?

Comment: Why can't you use map iterator ?

Comment: If you're accessing items by index, isn't that an array? And can't you just for(int i=0; i < size_of_array; i++) to iterate over it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're using as an index?  If you're using numbers, you could just use a `vector`.  Also, waht do you mean by "iterating over consecutive elements?"  Could you just use `std::map`'s provided iterators to iterate over elements near the one you found?

Comment: In my specific case, I want to maintain a list of appointments. The index would be the start time. (Yes, I would need to use a `multimap` in this case. I left that out for simplicity's sake.) An array would not fit my needs here. I could use `map::iterator`, but I read that iterator incrementation has `O(log(n))` complexity for this structure.

Comment: Instead of 'index', you probably mean 'key'. That was throwing people off. As for your question, `O(log n)` is really cheap. Try it in practice before you declare that it's too expensive.

Comment: I wanted to add a comment, but it was too long so I posted it as an answer. @Novelocrat appears to have figured out the index/key issue. If this is correct, I suggest editing the title to "linked list structure with a random-access by key"

Comment: Sorry about that, folks. I updated my post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you care about order in which you iterate:

Moving iterator from one element to the next is an O(c) operation both in the `list` and in the `(multi)map`, except c is slightly smaller for the `list`, so it is unlikely you'll gain much by combining the two.

You are probably best-off just using the `map` alone. The `map` naturally sorts its elements in the order of the key (appointment start time in your case), so you can easily iterate in that same order. Finding an individual element is O(log(n)). This is appropriate when collection needs to be mutable.

Alternatively, you could just store elements in a `vector`, then sort it before you need to iterate. After the sort, you can find an individual element via `binary_search` (O(log(n))) and iterate naturally with excellent performance (but still O(c)). Sorting is expensive, so this is appropriate only when collection is (mostly) immutable.

### If you don't care about order in which you iterate:

Just use the `unordered_(multi)map` - with proper hashing it will tend to be faster than the `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Novelocrat probably has it correct.  The idea is a container of appointments, accessible with a key of start-time.

If this really is a case where iterating consecutive elements of a multimap is too slow, one alternative is to keep the data in a list, then separately maintain a multimap where keys can be used to look up a shared_ptr or iterator into the list. The cost is more overhead on inserts and deletes, but optimized access for both random lookup and consecutive iteration.

Unless you are dealing with extremely large amounts of data and strict performance requirements a multimap alone probably performs well enough.  For extreme cases, putting the data in a list + using a map or multimap for lookups gives better performance, at the cost of extra code and the potential for errors where the keys are not kept in sync with the data.